# Установить равное положение объектов

Tags: html, table

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма ввода и кнопка находятся на разных уровнях, не смотря на то, что обоим **td** присвоено **valign="middle"**

Код:

```
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="80%" valign="middle">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                        <label class="control-label">Введите название песни...</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="middle">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md-2">Найти</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table width="100%">
            <tr class="form-group">
              <td width="100%" valign="middle">
                    <div class="">
                        <label class="control-label">Введите название песни...</label> 
                    </div>
                </td> 
            </tr> 

              <tr class="form-group"> 
                <td width="80%" valign="middle">
                    <div class=""> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="middle"> 
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md-2">Найти</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```